# Command line list processes using most CPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

I am looking for a command line tool / script to periodically capture and store the total cpu usage percentage and processes that are taking most of CPU, similar to `sysinternals process explorer` screenshot I have pasted below.

I have tried

```
C:\Windows\system32>typeperf "\process(*)\% processor time" -sc 1
```

This outputs two rows, with process names in first row and CPU usage in second, e.g.

```
C:\Windows\system32>typeperf "\process(_Total)\% processor time" "\process(mcshield)\% processor time" -sc 1

"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\****\process(_Total)\% processor time","\\****\process(mcshield)\% processor time"
"01/25/2021 09:06:44.599","792.840227","29.364453"

The command completed successfully.
```

**Since the computer has 8 cores, can I simply divide this by 8 to get the "current" CPU usage percentage?**

I checked `sysinternal pslist`. It has one process per row, but I can't figure out what the numbers mean in terms of CPU %.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pslist -nobanner
Process information for W-2D5TQQ2:

Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time
Idle                  0   0   8    0     60     4:38:55.890     1:19:32.649
System                4   8 289 5662    216     0:28:33.656     1:19:32.649
Secure System        72   8   0    0    184     0:00:00.000     1:19:40.412
Registry            128   8   4    0  14012     0:00:13.406     1:19:40.225
smss                620  11   2   53   1188     0:00:01.015     1:19:32.630
csrss               960  13  13  901   1932     0:00:20.796     1:19:08.909
wininit             648  13   1  163   1372     0:00:00.218     1:19:04.494
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think Windows keeps this history. Try Resource Monitor this time, let it run for an hour and export that log to get the kind of data you want. You can do a Save As with Process Explorer as well.

Comment: @John I don't mind writing a script to periodically capture the stats. But it needs to run on its own, without any user activity (e.g. Save As In procexp). I see my question is a little ambiguous, I will try to clarify

Comment: "pslist. It has one process per row, but I can't figure out what the numbers mean in terms of CPU %." - the CPU time is the amount of CPU time that process has used since it started, and elapsed time is the total time the process has been running, these are shown in  hours:mins:seconds.msec. Looks like you have 4 logical cores.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you are right, Windows `Task Manager` says I have 4 Cores and 8 Logical processors. Regarding `pslist` if I understand you right it cannot be used to see which processes are *currently* taking most CPU the way `procexp` does, correct?